# Random number from an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, random

I tried to generate a sorted list of random data with no duplicates in descending order for my array. It also returns number of duplicates, but it keeps printing out nothing but zero .... Can anyone help me please :(

```
// 2. Ask the user for size of arbitrary numbers.
System.out.print("Please enter a size for arbitray numbers: ");
int size = indata.nextInt(); 
int [] SortedNumbers = new int [size];

// 3. Process arbitrary numbers and remove all duplicates
int numDuplicates = generate_data(SortedNumbers);

// 4. Print the numbers and number of duplicates
printArray(SortedNumbers, numDuplicates);
```

and here is the random method

```
public static int generate_data (int [ ] list){
    int duplicates = 0;         
    Random random = new Random();
    System.out.println(n[random.nextInt(n.length)]);
    return duplicates;
}
```

here is the print_array method

```
public static void printArray(int [] list, int duplicates) {
// Additional code required
System.out.println("\nSize of array: " + list.length + "  .Numbers of duplicates: " + duplicates); for (int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
System.out.printf("%7d", list[i]);
if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0){
System.out.println();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
random.nextInt(n.length)
```

gives you a random index of your array.
But printing the value corresponding to this index, will always give you `0`. As you never store any other value in the array.

You should rather do something like this :

```
    int[] list = new int[10];
    int duplicates = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        int nextVal = random.nextInt(list.length);
        System.out.println("list["+i+"] = "+ nextVal);
        // test duplicates
        for (int index = 0; index < i; index++) {
            if (list[index] == nextVal) {
                duplicates++;
                break;
            }
        }
        list[i] = nextVal;
    }
    return duplicates;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `generate_data` method always returns `0`, since the local field `duplicates` is initialized with a `0` value and never changed.

The `n` field referenced by your `generate_data` method (which you haven't posted) is likely to be an `int[]`, but its elements might not have been initialized (hence the print out will print default value `0`, if within array index).

Hence your `numDuplicates` local field is always `0` too.

**Notes**

- Your `Random` initialization is not performing. You should initialize a `static Random` object in your class and re-use it, instead of re-initializing every time in your `generate_data` method.
- You probably want to have a look at [coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for Java in terms of field naming
- You might want to post the code in your `printArray` method as well

Comment: I don't quite understand :(